What does my tattoo really mean? It's sideways in the image. It's on my neck running downwards (Character identified: 卒)

This is a tattoo I received for hours in the Army. It supposedly means soldier, but I cannot find it anywhere. I was wondering if someone could tell me what it means?

卒在不同的语境或环境中表示不同的意思
As you said

It supposedly means soldier, but I cannot find it anywhere.

作为一个中国象棋爱好者 (https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E8%B1%A1%E6%A3%8B)，我知道你可以从哪里找到卒(发音：zu)表示士兵的意思，请看下图：

在中国象棋游戏中黑色一方的卒和对方(红色一方)的兵是一个意思，卒和兵在象棋游戏中都表示士兵的意思，象棋我感觉挺有趣的，有时候我也玩。
在医院的挂号处和抢救室(医学方面)，你也可以看到卒(发音是cù)，比如脑卒中，见链接 https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-cn/%E5%8D%92%E4%B8%AD ，卒又有急迫、仓促的意思，与“猝”通，

This seems to me 卒 (zú) (pronounced as "dzoo" with a rising tone, so as if you are asking a question and with a shorter "oo" sound) which is an old word for (foot) soldier (it can also mean "servant", and it can be used for the "pawn" in Chinese chess). In classical times it could also indicate the commander of a group of 25 soldiers (sergeant). The most common current character for soldier is 兵 (bīng), but perhaps 卒 might be considered a more elegant word (?).
The character 卒 consists of the radicals (components) 亠 (tóu, head,top) 从 (cóng, to follow: two people 人+人 following each other as it were) and 十 (shí, ten).
